# Angularjs: making a service dictionary Service to DI instead of individual services?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

Even with [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate), I'm **getting sick of declaring/updating dependencies** arrays and dependency injection params.
Especially on my controllers/directives.

**Could I create a super service that referenced all my services** without causing major problems?
Even if only for controllers and directives?

**Normal**:

```
ExportTransactionDirectiveDependencies = [
    "ApiBasicServiceModule"
    "CSVMakerServiceModule"
    "NgTableHelperServiceModule"
    "UtilServiceModule"
    "ExportTransactionsServiceModule"
]

ExportTransactionController = ($scope, $routeParams, ApiBasicService, UtilService, ExportTransactionsService)->

    # PRIVATE
    _bapi = ApiBasicService
    _u = UtilService
    _nh = NgTableHelperService
    _x = ExportTransactionsService
    _websiteId = $routeParams.website_id
    _meta = {}

    ...

angular
    .module 'ExportTransactionDirectiveModule', ExportTransactionDirectiveDependencies
    .directive 'exporttransaction', ExportTransactionDirective
```

**Proposed**:

```
ExportTransactionController = ($scope, $routeParams, RefService)->

    # PRIVATE
    _bapi = ServiceRefService.ApiBasicService
    _u = ServiceRefService.UtilService
    _nh = ServiceRefService.NgTableHelperService
    _x = ServiceRefService.ExportTransactionsService
    _websiteId = $routeParams.website_id

    ...

angular
    .module 'ExportTransactionDirectiveModule', ['RefServiceModule']
    .directive 'exporttransaction', ExportTransactionDirective
```

This means less maintenance of duplicated semantic/syntactic meaning, and shorter code. And I don't feel it loses its expressiveness as I have the services named in the '# PRIVATE' section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason you couldn't. It's basically an injector service with pretty syntax.

In my opinion - don't do it...

You'll be fighting against Angular's intent and it's got a half decent error logging system in place to help you debug and code better. No doubt it will catch you out at times if you're using services from different modules too.

I think you're over engineering a solution to a pretty insignificant problem - creating frustration and beard scratching for future developers.

Your code though.

Comment: Yeah, I've done stuff like this for personal projects which does work well. But this is a team project so I don't think I wanna rock the boat.